# c# Insert boolean value into database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have problem inserting boolean value into database. 
I have simple structure:

```
struct
{
   string name;
   bool isStudent;
}
```

and I want to insert it into data base like this:

```
 dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO People (name, isStudent) VALUES ('" + people1.name + "', " + people1.isStudent + ")";
 dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but i throws exception:

> SQLite error no such column: True

Comment: It's telling you that your field doesn't exist in your database.  What is your database structure?  `Describe database_table`

Comment: Insert `@string`, `@string = "Standard SQL injection warning."`

Comment: boolean values are stored as `bit`s `1` or `0` you need a `?` `:` for this, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO People (name, isStudent) VALUES ('" + people1.name + "', '" + people1.isStudent + "')";
```

Note that `'true'` or `'false'` will be quoted this way.

Or:

```
int val = isStudent ? 1 : 0;
dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO People (name, isStudent) VALUES ('" + people1.name + "', " + val + ")";
```

`1` will be used for true values and `0` for false values.

Answer (score 4):

Use parameters and you won't have to worry about quotes or format of the values (besides, it is a good practice to **avoid SQL injection**):

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO People (name, isStudent) 
                         VALUES (@name, @isStudent)";
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", people1.name);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isStudent", people1.isStudent);
dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't have a bool column type and you're constructing the SQL statement yourself.  If you want to do that, then convert 1 and 0 back and forth.

I would also think the .net wrapper would do that 4 u.  But you would have to use SQL parameters and not build the string yourself to even give it a chance to do that.

Building parameterized queries (?) also let's SQL lite cache the compiled statements.